# Multiple Level Rails Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

This is troubling me for days now. I have the simple setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inquiries, dependent: :destroy
end


class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
end


class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inquiry
end
```

The idea is to save the inquiries(tickets) a user submits and save the entries(replies) in another model with the relation.

In the Inquiry show view I have a form that submits to the entries Controller with a hidden field containing the Inquiry id.

```
= form_for @entry do |f|
  = f.label :message, t('views.message')
  = f.text_area :message
  = f.hidden_field :inquiry_id, :value => @inquiry.id

  .buttons
    = f.submit t('views.submit')
```

And the entries controller

```
def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
    @inquiry = Inquiry.find(params[:entry][:inquiry_id])
    @entry.inquiry = @inquiry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @inquiry, notice: 'Entry was created succesfully' }
        #format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @inquiry }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @inquiry, error: 'Entry could not be created.' }
        #format.json { render json: @inquiry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        logger.warn "Entry could not be created: #{@entry.attributes.inspect}, is valid?: #{@entry.valid?}"
     end
   end
 end

def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:message, :inquiry_id)
end
```

All the params are passed correctly but it fails to save the entry in the database. Is valid? returns false even tho theres no validation and no errors shown. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

From logger:

```
Entry could not be created: {"id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "i
nquiry_id"=>2, "author"=>nil, "message"=>"This is a test", "employee"=>nil}, is
valid?: false
```

And trying to save!

```
irb(main):023:0> @entry.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: translation missing: es.activerecord.errors.message
s.record_invalid
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returni
ng_status'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:i
 n `block in transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:i
n `within_new_transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:i
n `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in `with_transaction_returning_status
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4
.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
        from (irb):23
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4
/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4
/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4
/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Btw I have no validations for Entry and nil fiels are allowed. I also tried with all params filled including manually asigning an ID.

Comment: What/where is `entry_params`?

Comment: Likely unrelated, but you can clean this up quite a bit: `@inquery = Inquiry.find(...); @entry = @inquiry.entries.new(entry_params)` then remove `@entry.inquiry = @inquiry`

Comment: @meagar sorry I left it out. Just edited.

Comment: @meagar yes its cleaner now but as you said the problem persists

Comment: you could try using save!... save! will raise exceptions for the validation errors which might help you figure out why the validation is failing... (of course you could inspect the errors themselves by outputting them to your logger... but I think it's faster to use save!)

Comment: You say `@entry.valid?` is false?  What do you see when you inspect `@entry.errors.full_messages` ?

Comment: @user3334690 I used save! but didnt understand the output. Copied it above.

Comment: I feel like this is a case of nested attributes? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Are you sure your migrations are correct and that you've run them?  What do you get at the console by saying `Entry.new.save!`. Try posting `db/schema.rb`.  FWIW, the error message is nonsense because (apparently) the locale is set to Spanish and you don't have Spanish error messages defined.